# Footer - Use table or nested ULs?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a footer that looks something like this:

---

```
Item       |          Title          |   Image
Item       |   Item          Item    |
Item       |   Item          Item    | FB T Icons
Item       |   Item          Item    |   Item
```

It will be a fixed width (900px) as I will use a different design for smaller screens/mobile. The middle column is twice the size of the side ones, i.e. 225px/550px/225px, but the top title needs to be centered in it whilst the items below are in two columns.

There needs to be some styling (separating lines between the blocks and above and below).

I'm new to coding. Should I use nested ULs, or a table to achieve this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Tables should not be used for building layout. I would use ULs and headers.
Quick example:

```
<ul class="column">
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<div class="column column-2x">
    <header>Title</header>
    <ul class="column">
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="column">
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul class="column">
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice